# Задача "Гладкие числа"

Tags: python, c++

Назовём число гладким, если его цифры, начиная со старшего разряда, образуют неубывающую последовательность. Упорядочим все такие числа в возрастающем порядке и присвоим каждому номер. Требуется по номеру N вывести N-е гладкое число.

```
1 <= N <= 2147483647
```

Примеры:

```
Ввод: 3 Вывод: 3
Ввод: 11 Вывод: 12
```

Я написал такой код на Python:

```py
n = int(input())
result = ""
#В dp[i][j] записано кол-во гладких чисел длины i, начинающихся на цифру j
dp = [[0] * 10 for _ in range(n + 1)] #я немного не понял, откуда надо брать длину dp
for j in range(10):
    dp[1][j] = 1
for i in range(2, n):
    for j in range(10):
        dp[i][j] = sum(dp[i - 1][k] for k in range(10) if k >= j)
#Находим длину n-го гладкого числа
n_l = 1
for i in range(1, n):
    if dp[i + 1][0] >= n and dp[i][0] < n:
        n_l = i
        break
n -= dp[n_l][0]
#Находим первую цифру числа
j = 1
while n >= dp[n_l][j]:
    n -= dp[n_l][j]
    j += 1
result += str(j)
prev = j
#Находим оставшиеся цифры числа
if n_l > 1:
    while n > 0:
        for j in range(prev + 1, 10):
            if n <= dp[i - 1][j]:
                n -= dp[i - 1][j]
                result += str(j)
                prev = j
                break
            n -= dp[n_l - 1][j]
print(result)
```

Данный код работает только на маленьких значениях N. Что в нём исправить, для того, чтобы оно работало и на больших значениях N (N <= 2147483647)

Comment: Ну если требуется - то выведите!

Comment: Надо "гладкие" числа генерировать, а не проверять каждое число на "гладкость". На таких больших диапазонах большая часть проверок вообще лишняя, потому что есть огромные диапазаны "негладких" чисел. После, например, 199999 идет 200000 и еще 22222 "негладких" числа. Итого 22223 негладких числа. Зачем же их проверять, если и так понятно, что они негладкие.

Comment: Вы сами написали этот код? Или позаимствовали его? Это важно, что бы понять, что именно вам в нём не понятно?

Comment: Код я писал сам. Мне был дан алгоритм для решения подобной задачи (только там надо было найти число по номеру, соседние цифры которого отличаются не более чем на три). По нему я писал решение этой задачи

Comment: В массиве первое измерение должно быть не `n`, а сколько в `n` десятичных позиций.

Comment: Писать такие программы по образцу - плохая идея. Надо бы начинать с выписывания рекурсивной функции. Затем под неё сочинять динамику (кеш значений функции). Тогда подобных ошибок не будет.

Comment: @Эникейщик, хорошо. И как же Вы предлагаете их генерировать?

Comment: посидеть, придумать алгоритм и реализовать его в код. Вот так примерно это делается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

> ```
> 7??? # сколько гладких числе имеют такой вид?
>      # все они могут быть одного из видов ниже
> 77??
> 78??
> 79??
> ```

Если `f(k, d)` - число гладких чисел с цифрой `d` в разряде `k`, то `f(k, d) = sum(d <= e < 10, f(k - 1, e))`. Краевое условие `f(1, d) = 1`.

Тогда функцию `f` вычисляет такой код:

```
@functools.cache
def f(k, d):
    if k == 1:
        return 1
    return sum(f(k - 1, e) for e in range(d, 10))
```

С помощью функции `f` можно "собрать" `n`-ое число из цифр. Код для вычисления `m` - количества цифр в ответе:

```
    m = 1
    while f(m + 1, 0) <= n:
        m += 1
```

Цифры `n`-ого числа подбираются от старших разрядов к младшим. `d` - последняя подобранная цифра, k - разряд:

```
    d = 0
    s = 0
    for k in range(m, 0, -1):
        for d in range(d, 10):
            if s + f(k, d) > n:
                break
            s += f(k, d)
        yield d
```

Всё вместе:

```
import functools


@functools.cache
def f(k, d):
    if k == 1:
        return 1
    return sum(f(k - 1, e) for e in range(d, 10))


def g(n):
    m = 1
    while f(m + 1, 0) <= n:
        m += 1

    d = 0
    s = 0
    for k in range(m, 0, -1):
        for d in range(d, 10):
            if s + f(k, d) > n:
                break
            s += f(k, d)
        yield d
    assert s == n


print(*g(int(input())), sep='')
```

> ```
> $ echo 3 | python nth-smooth.py 
> 3
>
> $ echo 11 | | python nth-smooth.py 
> 12
>
> $ echo 2147483647 | python nth-smooth.py 
> 11111111333333344444444444444777777778999
>
> $ time echo 1000000000000000000000000000000000000 | python nth-smooth.py | wc -c
> 41468
>
> real  0m0.927s
> user  0m0.884s
> sys   0m0.040s
> ```

## Дополнение

Функция `f(k, d)`, оказывается равна `Cnk(k + 8 - d, 9 - d)`. В предыдущей реализации функцию `f` можно заменить на ...

```
def f(k, d):
    return math.comb(k + 8 - d, 9 - d)
```

... и будет работать быстрее. Доказательство это факта не сложно, опущу его пока. Я надеялся что прямое вычисление `Cnk` сделает реализацию на C++ проще и короче но ошибся. Проще заполнить массив со значениями `f`:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void g(uint64_t n) {
    std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>> f(1); // unused zero column/row
    f.emplace_back(10, 1);                   // f(1, d) == 1
    unsigned m = 1;
    for (; ; ) {
        f.emplace_back(10);
        uint64_t s = 0;
        for (int d = 9; d >= 0; --d) {
            s += f[m][d];
            f[m + 1][d] = s;
        }
        if (f[m + 1][0] > n) {
            break;
        }
        ++m;
    }

    unsigned d = 0;
    for (unsigned k = m; k > 0; --k) {
        for (unsigned e = d; e < 10; ++e) {
            if (f[k][e] > n) {
                d = e;
                break;
            }
            n -= f[k][e];
        }
        std::cout << d;
    }
    assert(n == 0);
}

int main() {
    uint64_t n;
    std::cin >> n;
    g(n);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Нормально работает до числа `18348006354228436599 = Cnk(577, 9) - 1`:

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror nth-smooth.cpp 
>
> $ echo 3 | ./a.out 
> 3
>
> $ echo 11 | ./a.out 
> 12
>
> $ echo 2147483647 | ./a.out 
> 11111111333333344444444444444777777778999
>
> $ echo 18348006354228436599 | ./a.out 
> 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
> ```

Comment: Ваш код решает задачу на Python'е. Единственная проблема: это надо решить ещё и на C++, и если `yeld` можно легко на плюсы переписать, то вот с `functools.lru_cache()` всё куда сложнее...

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях предлагали генерировать гладкие числа.
Я придумал такой вариант:

```py
def f(n : str) -> str:
    if n[-1] == '9':
        if len(n) == 1:
            return str(int(n) + 2)
        tmp = f(n[:-1])
        return tmp + str(int(tmp[-1]))
    else:
        return str(int(n) + 1)

n = int(input())
result = '1'
while n > 1:
    result = f(result)
    n -= 1
print(result)
```

Но он работает слишком медленно